# Flickr API: Upload an image with python

Tags: python, oauth, python-requests, flickr

I have a problem to upload an image trought the Flickr API.

I use OAuthLib-requests (https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib)

The Flickr doc: https://secure.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html

My code:

```
params = {
    'format'         : 'json',
    "nojsoncallback" : "1",
    'api_key'        : 'my_api_key',
}

with open('myfile.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    files = {'file': f}

    r = the_oauth_requests_session.post('https://up.flickr.com/services/upload/', params=params, files=files)
    print r.content
```

But in the content I can find this error: 'No photo specified'.

What is the way to upload a photo ?

I'm authenticated, and others api calls work perfectly (like 'flickr.photosets.create')

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not use something like [flickrapi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flickrapi) to handle all of the heavy lifting for you?

Comment: Because I need a Python 3 support :/

Comment: judging by https://bitbucket.org/sybren/flickrapi/issue/36/python-3-compatibility it would seem the library will soon support Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple:

```
files = {'photo': f}
```

Instead of:

```
files = {'file': f}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Flickr does not let you upload any other file types than images and videos.
In your code:

```
files = {'file': f}
```

are you sure 'file' is of the right type?